# Difference between API and adapters

Tags: api, adapter

Its been hard for me to understand difference between **API** and **adapters** .Can anyone clarify what is API and Adapters and how it is different from each other.

Answer (score 1):

An API is an Application Programming Interface which presents an interface between different libraries, frameworks, applications and services.

An adapter is a design pattern used to allow the interface of an existing class to be used as another interface.

An Api is thus somewhat external, while an adapter is more concerned with the inner source code.